# Regular expression C# issue ( underscore)

Tags: c#, regex, validation

How can I make a regex that let me put a mandatory underscore "_" at any position of a string of characters.

My initial regex is: `^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}$`
that means: lower and upper case letters and decimal digits. I've tried escaping the underscore like this: \_

The conditions to the match are: 
Mandatory: Uppercase letters, Lowercase letters, Underscore "_"
Optional: Numbers (decimal digits)

Sample match strings:

> _Hola
>
> H_o1a
>
> Ho_l3
>
> H0l_a
>
> Hola_

Comment: Tried `^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,5}$`?

Comment: Do you mean there can be any amount of `_`, but there must be 1 to 5 alphanumeric chars?

Comment: Could you supply a sample input and desired output?

Comment: Regular expression seems like a poor choice for validating strong passwords... I would use a set of boolean "rule validator" objects that can also return an invalidity reason description.

Comment: Am I missing something? How about something like this `^[a-zA-Z0-9]*_[a-zA-Z0-9]*$`?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static bool TryMatchWithRegex(string txt, out string result)
{
    result = string.Empty;
    // Mandatory= underscore, lowercase, uppercase
    string pattern = @"^(?=.*_)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).*$";
    Regex regex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.None);
    Match match = regex.Match(txt);
    if (match.Success)
    {
        result = match.Value;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```